# Populating HTML fields from a HTML table, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've written a JQuery function, to generate a HTML table. That's all working fine. I'm now trying to write another JQuery function (populateUpdateFilm), to access those table values and populate separate HTML fields on the same screen. I've bound this new function to the 'Update Film' button on the webform.

I've referred to the JQuery documentation and written a function, but it's not working as expected. There are no errors in the browser, when I use 'Inspect Element'.

Can anyone help? Code attached.

**Webform.xhtml**

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Get Film By ID</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="filmid"/></label><br></br>
            <input type="button" value="XML"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'xml', 'filmid')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'json', 'filmid')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'text', 'filmid')"/>

            <input type="button" value="Update Film"
                    onclick="populateUpdateFilm()"/>
        </form>
        <p/>
        <div id="getfilmbyid"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Update Film Details</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="u_filmname"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Year: <input type="text" id="u_year"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Cast: <input type="text" id="u_stars"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Director: <input type="text" id="u_director"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Plot: <input type="text" id="u_review"/></label><br></br>
        </form>
        <p/>
        <div id="updatefilm"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>
```

**JQuery Function**

```
function populateUpdateFilm() {

    $("#getfilmbyid"), function() {

        let tableRow = $(this).closest("tr");

        // starts at index 1, as I don't need the first td value (id)

        let u_filmname = tableRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        let u_year = tableRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
        let u_stars = tableRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        let u_director = tableRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
        let u_review = tableRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();

        $("#u_filmname").append(u_filmname);
        $("#u_year").append(u_year);
        $("#u_stars").append(u_stars);
        $("#u_director").append(u_director);
        $("#u_review").append(u_review);

    }
}
```

**Browser Element Output For Table**

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="getfilmbyid">
<table border="1" class="ajaxTable">
<tr>
  <th>Film Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Year</th>
  <th>Director</th>
  <th>Cast</th>
  <th>Plot</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>10008</td>
  <td>A FEW GOOD MEN</td>
  <td>1992</td>
  <td>ROB REINER</td>
  <td>TOM CRUISE, JACK NICHOLSON</td>
  <td>After the mysterious death of a young Marine in the barracks, a young navy Lawyer (Cruise) is called in to investigate. The further he delves into the mystery the more he is thwarted by the fearsome and unyielding  Colonel Nathan Jessup (Nicholson), a man who knows the truth and is determined to conceal it....</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What's happening now? (i.e. can you be clearer on 'not working as expected' ?)

Comment: This code is intended to extract data from an html table but there's no such table on your html. It's not clear what's the point for `$("#getfilmbyid"), function() {` and `}`. I guess you are missing relevant parts of the code in your question.

Comment: hi @RachelGallen nothing is happening when i click the 'Update Film' button. no response at all in the browser. i've added a break point at the populateUpdateFilm function, but the browser just skips over the function

Comment: @derloopkat thanks. the table is already rendered in the browser at this point. the getFilmById function does that, and places the table in div id "getfilmbyid". my understanding was i could now use $("#getfilmbyid) to 'select' the content in the div id, i.e. the table?

Comment: @RachelGallen by 'runnable' do you mean sharing the full set of executable code, or just a screenshot of the web page showing the displayed html table? it's a client-server MVC app and there's quite a bit of of code involved, to render the html table: webform, jquery, js, servlet, model beans, dao class & jsp. everything up to rendering the table is fine. it's the bit after that, to access the table td values then populate the 'Update Film' fields

Comment: @mcooling .. runnable means executable! A minimal and verifiable example is desired to solve any question on stackoverflow. Not a screenshot, just  the result of the jsp or part of it anyway (not the full table)... but source code of the table with some values in it.

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen. I've inspected the elements in the browser, for the div id where the table is inserted. I've added the output to the code block above. Hope that helps.

Comment: @mcooling Two comments.. 1) you don't have a submit button in the update part of your code (it's coded as a div not an actionable button) .. actually it's not within the form either.. also your form isn't doing anything .. where are you calling the populate function? I'd expect that to be called in an onsubmit function but there is none.. or on the click of a button.. do you have an eventListener?

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen. All the buttons in the webform are bound to jQuery functions, using onclick, e.g. 'Update Film' button is bound to the jQuery populateUpdateFilm() function and the 'XML', 'JSON' and 'TEXT' buttons are bound to the getFilmById function